# Make Array accessible from multiple functions (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to make a basic login/password array feature to work with my html/css files. I am used to java - making the array public by declaring it outside the functions but I'm not sure if thats correct. I can't seem to find what's going wrong with my code, any help would be much appreciated!

JavaScript:

```
var count = 2;
var unArray = ["Philip", "George", "Sarah", "Michael"];
var pwArray = ["Password1", "Password2", "Password3", "Password4"]; 

function validate() {
    var un = document.myform.username.value;
    var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
    var valid = false;

    for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        return false;
    }

    var t = " tries";
    if (count == 1) {
        t = " try";
    }

    if (count >= 1) {
        alert ("Invalid username and/or password.  You have " + count + t + " left.");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
        count --;
    } else {
        alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
        document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        document.myform.username.disabled = true;
        document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }

}

function addMember(){
    var newun = document.signup_form.new_username.value;
    var newpw = document.signup_form.new_pword.value;
    var valid=true;

    for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if (newun == unArray[i]) {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(valid){
        unArray.push("newun"");
        pwArray.push("newpw");
        alert ("Signup was successful");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert ("Username Taken");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AI Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="LoginPage.css">
    <script src="LoginPage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav id="top_menu">
            <ul>
                <button id="Home" onclick="location.href= 'AIWebsite.html';" style="border:none" ;> HOME </button>
                <button id="RecentNews" onclick="location.href= 'RecentNewsPage.html'" style="border:none;">RECENT NEWS</button>
                <button id="R&D" onclick="location.href= 'ResearchPage.html';" style="border:none;">RESEARCH & DEVELOPMENT</button>
                <button id="Timeline" onclick="location.href= 'TimelinePage.html'" style="border:none;">TIMELINE</button>
                <button id="Ethics" onclick="location.href= 'EthicsPage.html'" style="border:none;">ETHICS</button>
                <button id="Journals" onclick="location.href= 'JournalsPage.html'" style="border:none;">JOURNALS</button>
                <button id="Login" onclick="location.href= 'LoginPage.html'" style="border:none;">LOGIN</button>
        </nav>
        <form name="myform">
            <div id="login_area">
                <p>
                    ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" name="username"> ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="pword">
                    <input type="button" value="Log in" name="Submit" onclick="validate()">
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
        <h2> Or Sign Up </h2>
        <form name="signup_form">
            <div id="signup_area">
                <p>
                    Enter User Name <input type="text" name="new_username"> Enter Password <input type="password" name="new_pword">
                    <input type="button" value="Sign Up" name="Sign_up" onclick="addMember()">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
    display:block;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    background: blue;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#container{
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#top_menu button{ 
    display:inline-block;
    font: 18px Neue Helvetica;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    color:#D0D0D0; 
    background:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#Login{
    float:right;
}
#login_area{
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#signup_area{
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
h2{
    margin-top: 150px;
}
button:focus {outline:0;}
```

Comment: If you're going to store passwords in the script, what's worth of the login anyway?

Comment: Anyone who knows how to use inspect element or view source will see the usernames/passwords so having a javascript login would be pretty useless.

Comment: Ah I see, but just for the sake of knowing, are the arrays made publicly accessible to each function if initiated outside the functions or is that just in java?

Comment: It would be available in the global scope on window variable, so you can access those variables from anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried window.unArray?

Comment: Correct, the array is public so you can access it with any function.